# Stress in the question: How about you?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

If I transcribe this question "How about you?" to IPA it looks like: [ haʊ əˈbaʊt yu]. The dictionary shows the word "about" with primary stress on its second syllable but I think in my question it loses the stress:

[context] Hi. How are you? ... I'm fine. How about you?

The way I say it sounds more like this: [ haʊ(w)əbaʊtʃyu ] with some stress on "how" and "you": https://clyp.it/oazaugqw

I would be grateful for your suggestion regarding the stress in my situation.

Comment: Your pronunciation sounds normal and natural to my (native AmE) ear That's about all I have to offer, though.

Comment: With the small quibble that 'you' in IPA should be /ju/ or /ju:/, this native British speaker agrees with the way you're saying it.